# Integral transforms involving square roots

Tags: integral-transforms

I am considering the following integral equation

$\frac{1}{y} = \int_a^{\infty} g(x,y) x^{-1/2} dx$,

where $g(x,y)$ is to-be-determined and $a$ is a positive constant (if it is instructive, it can be taken to be zero, but I am really interested in the $a > 0$ case.) I am wondering if there are any sources/literature that discuss this type of kernel?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not an integral transform.    You can think of each $y$ as giving you a separate equation for $g(\cdot, y)$, which is the appropriate multiple of  any $f \in L^1([a,\infty), x^{-1/2}\; dx)$ with $\int_{a}^\infty f(x) x^{-1/2} dx \ne 0$.